# Posting json to mvc 4 WebApi controller action. Why doesn't it deserialize my array?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

The following has been driving me a bit crazy. I have found a couple of similar problems but they did not offer a solution. I am trying to post a json object containing a few data items. One of them is a list of object itself. Here it is:

```
{
"ClaimType":"Trade",
"ClaimedProductId":"4",
"ClaimingUserId":"2",
"Message":"test",
"TradeOffers":[
  {
     "OfferedProductId":"7",
     "OfferedQuantity":"5"
  },
  {
     "OfferedProductId":"12",
     "OfferedQuantity":"2"
  }
]
}
```

This json validates.

My controller looks like this:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Claim(ClaimViewModel claimViewModel)
    {
        //do some amazing stuff with the data from the viewmodel.
        //sorry guys. This stuff is just tooo cool to be posted here for all to see
        //NOT ;-)  
    }
}
```

The ClaimViewModel I am posting looks like this:

```
public class ClaimViewModel
    {
    public Claim.ClaimRequestTypes ClaimType { get; set; } 
    public int ClaimedProductId { get; set; }
    public int ClaimingUserId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<TradeOffer> TradeOffers { get; set; }
    }
```

For completeness sake, here's the TradeOffer class:

```
public class TradeOffer
{
    int OfferedProductId { get; set; }
    int OfferedQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

Before I staring posting from Javascript, I like to use the Chrome RestConsole to test this bad boy, so I can look a bit better under the hood. I make a request with the following settings:

- its a POST request
- the BODY Content Type is "application/json"
- I send the json as the Request Payload in the RAW Body

Then here's what happens: all properties on my `ClaimViewModel` get deserialized nice and easy. However, the `TradeOffers` property get instantiated and when debugging shows a list with a count of 2 (so far so good) but the values of the objects in this list (properties `OfferedProductId` and `OfferedQuantity`) are always 0/zero (not null!)

Comment: On your JSON, the field name for your array is `TradeOffer`; in your class definition it's `TradeOffers`. Try making them the same to see if it helps.

Comment: if you're using jquery, try setting `traditional:true` in your request. MVC doesn't like the norm (or should I blame it on m$)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Properties in `TradeOffer` class are private (default access modifier in C#), which makes it impossible to set them from outside. Try making them `public`:

```
public class TradeOffer
{
    public int OfferedProductId { get; set; }
    public int OfferedQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! This - very simple - oversight fixed it! Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Are your properties in TradeOffer really private?  If so, those need to be public.

In addition,

```
public List<TradeOffer> TradeOffers { get; set; }
```

should be

```
public List<TradeOffer> TradeOffer { get; set; }
```

OR you should change the name to the plural version in your JSON collection

Comment: Thanks guys! This - very simple - oversight fixed it! Thank you for pointing it out!